# DRY in javascript for dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just starting out with Javascript so the query/question, I have a dynamic field script (not mine) which adds/subtracts with a press of a button. Works good, does the job.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count

  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
  <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v7uzef1g/)

But what if I need to add 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 dynamic fields in the same form. Do I need to repeat this javascript (up top) same to same every time for each field I need to make dynamic or is there a better way of doing it keeping DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) methodology intact?

**Scenario**

Say I have 2 fields `<input type = "text" name="phonenumber">` and `<input type = "text" name="faxnumber">` in a form. I need both of them to be dynamic. The user may have 3 phone numbers and 2 fax number. So 3 phone fields and 2 fax fields will be used. To have, two different fields (or for that matter 3 or 4) to be dynamic, do I need to repeat the javascript for each and every field.

**EDIT**

I edited this for anyone to have a perfect glimpse to as to what I have been trying to do. This may not be the right way or maybe it is. I do not know as said earlier I am new to this stuff.

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 5; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count

    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="phone[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields_fax      = 5; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper_fax         = $(".input_fields_fax"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button_fax      = $(".add_field_fax"); //Add button ID

    var y = 1; //initlal text box count

    $(add_button_fax).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(y < max_fields_fax){ //max input box allowed
            y++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper_fax).append('<div><input type="text" name="fax[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper_fax).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); y--;
    })
});
```

Here up top I repeated the Javascript twice with a few tweaking the names of the variables and classes

**HTML**

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="phone[]"></div>
</div>
<div class="input_fields_fax">
    <button class="add_field_fax">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="fax[]"></div>
</div>
```

New [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v7uzef1g/1/).

If you need 3 phone fields, press the button three times and if you need 2 fax fields press the second add more field 2 times. We now have 3 phone fields and 2 fax fields in the same form. My question is how can I do this more efficiently.

Comment: You can loop `$(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
`

Comment: Say I have 2 fields <input type = "text" name="phonenumber"> and <input type = "text" name="faxnumber"> in a form. I need both of them to be dynamic. User may have 3 phone numbers but 2 fax number. So 3 phone fields and 2 fax fields will be used. I am new but do not see how the loop helps.

Comment: Do you need 5 fields every time you click?

Comment: No sir, say a user may want to add 3 phone numbers and 2 fax number. Both are different fields and the user depending on his needs will generate 3 phone field but only 2 fax field dynamically.

Comment: No easy way to do that. You can have all possible fields on screen and hide unused ones. Then no need to add to the DOM

Comment: I think it can be done by repeating the javascript for every individual field I need to get dynamic, not tried though, but I was thinking about not repeating the javascript somehow. Not sure so looking for answers.

Comment: You can have some JS object with `{ phone: { maxFields:2, name: "phone[]"}. fax: { title: "Who has a fax nowadays",maxFields:3, name:"fax[]" }}` and use that to access when user click an "add phone" or "add fax" link

Comment: I am new to this ... can you please alter the Fiddle and show me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created an object that holds some information about the field you add.

Note how I add the id to the button as a data attribute

```js
var fields = {
  phone: {
    title: "Phone number",
    maxFields: 2,
    numFields: 0,
    name: "phone[]"
  },
  fax: {
    title: "Fax (really?)",
    maxFields: 3,
    numFields: 0,
    name: "fax[]"
  }
}

$(function() {
  $(".add_button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var whatField = fields[this.id];
    if (whatField.numFields < whatField.maxFields) { //max input box allowed
      whatField.numFields++; //text box increment
      $("#wrapper").append('<div>' + whatField.title + '<input type="text" name="' + whatField.name + '"/><a href="#" data-id="' + this.id + '" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });

  $("#wrapper").on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    fields[$(this).data("id")].numFields--;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap" id="wrapper">
  <button class="add_button" id="phone">Add Phone</button>
  <button class="add_button" id="fax">Add Fax</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You, sir, are a Genius ... thank you. Your solution looks a lot dapper mine was repeat, repeat ...